# Can quotas and limits checked at organization level in Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota, limits

Please help me on my question,I spent a lot time to know the difference between quotas and limits and for checked out quotas at organization level.
As I am seeing some limits are their per organization level in IAm and VPC Quotas and limits section og Google cloud doc, so is it mean quotas and limits different.

Comment: Hello @Mahaboob. If the below solution helped then please consider to accept or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a difference between quotas and limits: you're able to change quotas, but you're not able to change limits.

---

Accordingly to the documentation [Working with Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota):

> Google Cloud enforces quotas on resource usage for project owners,
> setting a hard limit on how much of a particular Google Cloud resource
> your project can use.

and

> Quotas are enforced for a variety of reasons: for example, they
> protect the community of Google Cloud users by preventing unforeseen
> spikes in usage. Quotas also help you with resource management: for
> instance, you can set your own caps on service usage within your
> Google-provided quota while developing and testing your applications.
> Each quota limit is expressed in terms of a particular countable
> resource, from requests per day to an API to the number of load
> balancers used by your application.

**To change current quota limits** you can [request changes to quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) from the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.257687630.434987569.1607250683-1698584973.1584367323) page in the Cloud Console accordingly to the documentation:

> 1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.257687630.434987569.1607250683-1698584973.1584367323)  on the IAM & Admin page.
> 2. Open the **`Filter table`** and select **`Limit name`**: to search for a quota you want to adjust.
> 3. Select the **`Service`** for which you want to adjust your quota.
> 4. Make your selection from the drop-down options.
> 5. Edit your quota limit.
> 6. Click **`SAVE`**.
>
> A request to decrease quota is rejected by default. If you must reduce
> your quota, reply to the support email with an explanation of your
> requirements. A support representative from the Compute Engine team
> will respond to your request within 24 to 48 hours.

---

Accordingly to the documentation **limits cannot generally be increased unless specifically noted**. Please have a look at the VPC documentation [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota) section [VPC Limits](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#limits):

[image: limits]

same at the IAM documentation [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas) section [Limits](https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas#limits), and same for other GCP products and services.

Comment: Thanks Rohoza,So it's mean quota limit different and limits different? Can we use quotas at organization level,I see only limits are their per organization level is it correct?  And where we can find limits in google Console.

Comment: Yes, quota limits or quotas are different from limits of GCP products and services. You can find information about limits at the documentation pages, also you'll get a message at the Cloud Console if you try to go over the limit.

Comment: You should use quotas on the project level. Accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview#projects) "any Google Cloud resources that you allocate and use must belong to a project. You can think of a project as the organizing entity for what you're building. A project is made up of the settings, permissions, and other metadata that describe your applications. Resources within a single project can work together easily, for example by communicating through an internal network, subject to the regions-and-zones rules. "

Comment: Please accept/upvote my answer if it was helpful for you.